# HTTP Socket iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

One of our online systems has an API which can be called using HTTP Sockets.

There are many PHP classes for HTTP Sockets, but I'm kinda lost with iPhone.. This is one of the first time I have to use sockets, so I was wondering if someone could tell me how to do this.

What I basically need is:
We have a API which has a function like CREATE_USER and needs parameter Name & parameter Address for example, in the past you could call:
http://user:pass@blabla.com/CREATE_USER?Name=Someone&Place=Somewhere but then I get the HTML of the logon page as a response. What I need is the response from the server like "Creation user: OK"

But it now has to be done with sockets. Who can help me and maybe provide me with an example how to get the response from the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "you have to use sockets"?  This has always been the case.  HTTP traditionally goes over TCP port 80.  Are you referring to HTML 5 Web Sockets?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not referring to HTML5 Web Sockets. It's a normal HTTP Socket which runs under port 3030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friends are [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Examples: [SimpleURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245) [AdvancedURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I know it should be possible with those but I can't figure out how to use it to request the response of the url with user credentials etcetera. Do you have any example available?